# Não verificar valor da propriedade PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de instanciar uma conexão em PHP e não mostrar os valores como exemplo o usuário e senha, se utilizar o print_r(new nomedaclasse) é mostrado os valores mesmo utilizando o modificador private. É possível omitir as informações como os valores de usuário e senha? Segue parte do código:

```
    private $host="localhost";
    private $user="root";
    private $password="";
    private $dbname="test";         

    private function setLogin($l, $s){  
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname","$this->user", "$this->password");                            
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
        $conn = $conn->prepare("SELECT login, senha FROM usuario where login = :login and senha = :senha");
        $conn->bindParam(':login', $l, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $conn->bindParam(':senha', $s, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $conn->execute();
        $linha = $conn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($linha == ""){
            echo "false";  
        }else{                  
            session_start();
            echo $_SESSION["logado"] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        }
    }
```

Comment: É só não utilizar o `print_r`. Se de alguma forma você deseja apresentar algumas informações da classe, basta criar um método que retorne uma *string* contendo os dados que você quer expor e quando for mostrar basta chamar este método.

Comment: Claro que é só não utilizar o print_r este tipo de resposta é óbvia. O objetivo é que ninguém que não conseguisse acessar a classe descobrisse este valores, vamos supor que eu não desce a opção de visualização de uma classe com conexão do DB então o maior motivo é este, que se ele desce um print_r não fosse possível verificar as info.

Comment: Parece-me que você está confundindo alguns conceitos. Visibilidade de atributos não servem para definir esse tipo de segurança. Se uma pessoa conseguir inserir um `print_r` no código, ela poderá acessar o arquivo de banco de dados diretamente para pegar esses dados, entende? A visibilidade ao tenta fazer com que você use corretamente uma classe em outra, não impede que o código seja acessado.

Comment: Oi Anderson, Maravilha e compreendido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) que se chamado fora da classe, vai mostrar só as propriedades públicas.

```
<?php

class foo {
    private $a;
    public $b = 1;
    public $c;
    private $d;
    static $e;

    public function test() {
        var_dump(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}

$test = new foo;
var_dump(get_object_vars($test));

$test->test();

// array(2) {
//   ["b"]=>
//   int(1)
//   ["c"]=>
//   NULL
// }
//
// array(4) {
//   ["a"]=>
//   NULL
//   ["b"]=>
//   int(1)
//   ["c"]=>
//   NULL
//   ["d"]=>
//   NULL
// }
?>
```